# Aws limits monitoring with Nagios

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, limit, aws-cli

I tried searching for this topic on Google and after many failed attempts I decided to post this as questions here.

What I want to achieve: Monitoring my aws limits using Nagios.

As I have understood aws cli can be used to get the limits of only few aws services, for more in depth cost management and service limit management one has to opt for trusted advisor. Unfortunately it's quite expensive.

So I was wondering if there's a much simpler way with Nagios in which I could get notified if any of the aws services for my account is hitting a limit?

What kind of service limit notification  strategy is used by organizations(That can't afford to buy a subscription of trusted advisor) that use Aws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: only few services can show their limit (and current usage) through CLI or API. I don't like it either :) We have three options here:

1. Create a parser that grabs information from AWS Console (there is an example code here: https://forrestbrazeal.com/2015/07/20/adventures-in-aws-automating-service-limit-checks/).
2. Buy Trusted Advisor (btw, you can get a Trusted Advisor report with API call).
3. Try using `awslimitchecker`. Cause someone already tried to solve this problem.
   https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/